# How to apply windows layout for XFCE4 standard utilities in Awesome WM

Tags: debian, xfce, awesome

What does the following icon mean in Awesome WM?

[image]

It seems that this icon mean that the window is maximized but it seems that I can't change this status for XFCE4 standard utilities like `xfce4-settings-manager` via Mod4+m, so they ignore current windows layout as a result.

Is there any way to prevent such behavior?

Comment: This one: https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/blob/master/themes/sky/layouts/floating.png

Comment: @phg And what does it actually mean?

Comment: It’s a [floating window](https://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Getting_started#Concepts).